# SQL Server 2012: many virtual log files with status 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability

I have a database in high availability mode with a Log file of 16GB. Running DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE) reveals that only 0.03% of the file is used. So I'd like to shrink the file. I performed full and transaction backups and tried to shrink, but nothing happens. I executed DBCC OPENTRAN but no transaction is open on the DB. Executing SELECT name,log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases; returns "NOTHING". But If I run DBCC LOGINFO I see 320 Virtual log files, with about 200 being marked with STATUS 2 (not reusabale). Does somebody know why these VLFs are marked as such?
Thanks

Comment: What high availibility technology are you using?. What is *initial Size* of log file can you see that from SSMS

Answer (score 1):

STATUS = 2 means that the VLF is not re-usable at this point in time, however, it would be available once you do a LOG backup if the database is in FULL RECOVERY mode.